# Creating directory in C, Windows, MinGW (CodeBlocks) code does not create directories

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to create a simple directory tree using C on Windows. However, my code does not create directories, just prints them out, and thats it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

void createDirTree(char *path)
{
    char *tmp = NULL, *start = NULL, *end = NULL, *slash = NULL;

    tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(path) + 1));
    strcpy(tmp, path);

    start = tmp;
    end = start + strlen(path);

    while (start < end)
    {
        char *slash = strchr(start, '/');
        if (strcmp(start, ".") != 0)
        {
            CreateDirectory(tmp, NULL);
            printf("going to make %s\n", tmp);
        }
        if (!slash)
        {
            break;
        }
        *slash = '/';
        start = slash + 1;
    }

    free(tmp);
}


int main()
{
    char path1[] = "./mydir/dir1/dir2/";
    char path2[] = "./mydir/dir1/dir2/dir45/";
    createDirTree(path1);
    createDirTree(path2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step 1, always check for errors. You neglect to do so when you call `CreateDirectory`. Do that and find out what went wrong. It is also rather disappointing that you added diagnostics code to your program but then failed to show the output to us. You can see it. Why should we be denied that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the output one would expect:

```
createDirTree ("root/test/test2");
```

produces

```
going to make root/test/test2
going to make root/test/test2
going to make root/test/test2
```

With this additional line right after the `strchr`:

```
while (start < end)
{
    slash = strchr(start, '/');
    if (slash) *slash = 0;  /* new line */
```

I get the following, more logical, output:

```
going to make root
going to make root/test
going to make root/test/test2
```

When you are following the advice on *error checks* for `CreateDirectory`: I think you can safely ignore and continue when you get an `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that all parts of the path will be created (if created at all) in the same directory. Once you have created the root directory you do not append the next part of the path, and you don't go into the new directory, which means that a path such as `"some\\path\\with\\folders"` will ***not*** create this hierarchy:

```
\
`-- some
    `-- path
        `-- with
            `-- folders
```

Instead it ***will*** create

```
\
|-- some
|-- path
|-- with
`-- folders
```

However, if you don't even get this tree, you should check what [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns. If it fails you need to check for that, and check what the error is. If you perform an operation that can fail, you should always check for failure.